# Is there any doubly linked list implementation in Java?

Tags: java, linked-list

I see JDK implementation of `LinkedList` internally contains `Node` inner class, which contains the address to next and previous.

So my doubt isn't `LinkedList` in java a doubly linked list. If not, why?

And how to implement our own doubly linked list?

Comment: This link discusses doubly-linked [List and Deque](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html) implementations.  Is that what you're linking for?

Comment: Ironically, there is no singly-linked list implementation in JDK: [Why LinkedList in Java is not a real Linked List?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14816936/why-linkedlist-in-java-is-not-a-real-linked-list)

Comment: Is there a built in circular linked list implementation in java too.. ?

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Yes, [`LinkedList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html) is a doubly linked list, as the Javadoc mentions :

> **Doubly-linked list implementation** of the List and Deque interfaces. Implements all optional list operations, and permits all elements (including null).
>
> All of the operations perform as could be expected for a **doubly-linked list**. Operations that index into the list will traverse the list from the beginning or the end, whichever is closer to the specified index.

Comment: Yes you are correct, But it does it internally and we do not have control over this.  I want to know if we can have access to previous Node in LinkedList ?

Comment: `linkedList.listIterator().previous()`.

Comment: @AvinashJethy What "control over this" are you lacking? If you require iterating backwards, use the `ListIterator` returned by `listIterator()` method.

Comment: @Eran I believe the user is asking for an interface which allows you to navigate the list from an arbitrary node. Iterators don't do that and the collections List interfaces don't expose such a structure at all - it would be something similar to Map.Entry. It's just not an interface anyone needs much, outside of homework.

Comment: @pvg `ListIterator<E> listIterator(int index);` does exactly that. Of course it has to traverse the linked list (either from the start or from the end) to get to the required node.

Comment: @Eran Using ListIterator we can only iterate backward .But if I want to get the previous element of a specific element .I want something like this : get(index).previousElement() . Do we need to implement our own customized DoublyLinkedList for this ?

Comment: @pvg exactly thts what i wanted to ask :)

Comment: @AvinashJethy ListIterator allows iteration in both directions. `listIterator(i).previous()` is what you are looking for.

Comment: @Eran heh yes, that does exactly that for the values of exactly that that are exactly not-that. A node interface gives you constant time access to prev/next which is one reason to use a doubly linked list. The other being fast insertion/removal. One way to fake this is by just sticking to arraylist and keeping track of the index - then you have constant time prev/next.

Comment: @pvg `A node interface gives you constant time access to prev/next` - you still have to traverse a linked list (from the start or from the end) until you reach that node. That's exactly what `listIterator(i)` does (and `get(i)` does as much work). After you obtain the ListIterator, `previous` and `next` run in constant time.

Comment: @Eran you're basically arguing that a ListIterator is equivalent to a Node interface. It isn't, which is why LinkedList has an internal Node abstraction. It just doesn't expose it, which is what the question is after.

Comment: I think we have to write our own DoublyLinkedList Implementation to access next and prev address/element of a specific indexed element, as java does not provide direct solution to this .Correct me if I am wrong

Comment: @pvg ListIterator provides access to the previous and next nodes. I never said it was equivalent to the "Node interface" (whatever that is - the internal implementation of LinkedList has an Entry class in Java 6 and Node class in Java 8, no interface. In both cases it's an implementation detail and shouldn't be exposed to the outside world, since it can be replaced in future Java versions).

Comment: @AvinashJethy `list.listIterator(i)` gives you access to the elements before and after the i'th element as well as their indices. It's not clear what else you need that's not covered by that. Even if you had access to the internal Node/Entry class, you'd have to iterate from the first or last Node of the list to reach the i'th Node. That's what ListIterator does for you.